# How to change in realtime a text in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, real-time-updates

programmers, I have this little code here: import time

```
def loop(args):
    a = 100.1
    b = 0.1

    a = a - b
    time.sleep(0.2)
    while a != 0:
        a = a - 1
        print(a)

loop(1)
```

And what I want is to make the print statement change in the screen in realtime instead of printing many times in another line like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJpMC.jpg. 
If there's any piece of text inside the docs of python, please link it here.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Do you mean to say you want a new window that displays a countdown timer?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the *newline* and the end of each `print()`, and use a *carriage return* instead:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time


def loop(args):
    a = 100.1
    b = 0.1

    a = a - b
    while a != 0:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        a = a - 1
        print(a, end='\r')
    print()

loop(1)
```